# Need help wiring up custom event in MSAccess VBA

Tags: vba, class, ms-access, events

I have a form with a button which calls a long running function in a code module. I want to return periodic status update messages to the form during this process. My initial thoughts were to supply a callback method to the function, but I don't think VBA supports that. So now I'm trying to do it with a custom class and events.

I've created a class module called "MessageHandler" which contains the following code:

```
Public Event OnMessageReceivedEvent(message As String)

Public Sub MessageReceived(message As String)
    RaiseEvent OnMessageReceivedEvent(message)
End Sub
```

At the top of my form, I declare:

```
Dim WithEvents FormMessageHandler As MessageHandler

Private Sub FormMessageHandler_OnMessageReceived(message As String)
    AppendLogMessage message
End Sub
```

Then in the code behind the button on the form:

```
Set FormMessageHandler = New MessageHandler
```

I then pass FormMessageHandler through to my long running function in my module and periodically call:

```
messageHandler.MessageReceived "Some progress update blah blah"
```

However FormMessageHandler_OnMessageReceived is never being called so the events aren't working. To me it seems logical FormMessageHandler is now registered as a listener to the OnMessageReceived event, but how does it know what method call to respond to the event. What seems to be missing is a way to specify something like:

```
FormMessageHandler.OnMessageReceivedEvent = FormMessageHandler_OnMessageReceived
```

From the searches I've done it looks like there is some sort of special constant like: 
    FormMessageHandler.OnMessageReceived = "[Event Procedure]"

Which may provide the missing link, but I don't know how to use it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've figured it out thanks to the excellent guide here: http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/creating-custom-events.html (it was actually on the third page http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/exploiting-access-class-module-events.html).

Turns out creation of the link to the method that will receive the event when raised is automatic if named a certain way and I'd missed the word **event** off the end of the name.

```
Private Sub FormMessageHandler_OnMessageReceived(message As String)
```

Should have been called:

```
Private Sub FormMessageHandler_OnMessageReceivedEvent(message As String)
```

The most reliable way to create this method is to do what the guide suggests:

> The WithEvents keyword is almost magical. Once you've qualified an
>   object declaration with WithEvents, the name of the object appears in
>   the drop-down list at the top of the class module, and the object's
>   events appear in the right drop-down list.

Selecting the FormMessageHandler object from the drop-list automatically created the method I needed to consume the event (and when I compared it to what I had I saw the mistake I'd made in naming).

Answer (score 0):

Is this status message something you want sent at regular intervals or only at certain points in code?

If the former, you might consider using the OnTimer event which will allow you to interrupt control and update the status field.  Something like the following might work for you:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.TimerInterval = 3000 'milliseconds
End Sub

Private Function ReallyLongFunction()
    For i = 1 To 99999
        'Do stuff
        DoEvents
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Me!Status = "My update status"
End Sub
```

If the latter I'm not sure why updating the form and doing a refresh wouldn't work.  I don't know if an event listener can really work in Microsoft Access.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, it's not a bad idea but my first preference would be to send back progress messages as certain points in the code are reached - messages kind of along the lines of "Clearing existing data from table....", "Importing data from file..." etc to give some real time feedback on whats happening